# Stick element to top after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make container/div in sidebar moving/following along with page scrolling down. It is not just a `position:fixed` container. It will move only when it should disappear being scrolled down. What is the best practice to implement?

Thank you

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ScrollingSidebar/ - it it exactly I was looking for :) Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we want to:

1. start at 260px from top (as defined in CSS)
2. **stick** at 24px from top (as defined in JS)

```js
var $sticky = $("#sticky"),
    pos = {
      abs : {position: "absolute",  top: parseInt($sticky.css("top"), 10) },
      fix : {position: "fixed",     top: 24 /* <<< SET AS DESIRED */ },
    };

$(window).on("load scroll", function() {
  var canFix = $(this).scrollTop() >= pos.abs.top - pos.fix.top;
  $sticky.css( pos[ canFix? "fix" : "abs" ] );
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 2000px;
  border: 4px dashed #444;
}
#sticky{
  height: 100px;
  background: #0bf;
  position:absolute;
  top: 260px;   /* <<< SET AS DESIRED */
}
```

```html
SCROLL!
<div id="sticky">STICK ME AT 24 FROM TOP</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```